# Running applescript during laptop sleep ends with error

Tags: ios, applescript

So I have an applescript (from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370531/catalina-backup-ios-devices-programatically/370850#370850?newreg=14a167f68b6b4b4faa86c0877fb000ba) that backs up my iphone over wifi.

It works perfectly when running manually.

Now, I want to schedule them periodically (daily) at some hour in the night.

I've tried using launchd and periodic services, but when they run the script in the night when laptop is sleeping, I get: "execution error: System Events got an error: Application isn’t running. (-600)"

Not sure what is not running - System Events or the Finder??
Any idea how to make the script work when lid is closed?

Comment: Which script are you referring to? I'm guessing you are running the command line tool to back up because that seems to be the simplest and what I would choose. I do have a poller script using idle handler that runs fine (simple offline script) even when my laptop is asleep. I would try scheduled run via Keyboard Maestro. On the other hand, my scripts that are triggered via Calendar don't work when my Mac is sleeping. I've never tried launchd because I find it cumbersome to use.

Comment: I'm referring to the applescript on comment 3 of that page (https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/370850/414403). The cfgutil command line doesn't work over wifi